# How can I create a patch to delete a folder and create new folder using diff?

Tags: linux, bash, diff, patch

For example I have two directories say *old* and *new*. The directory *old* has a sub-directory *abc* and the directory *new* has a sub-directory *cde*. 
I tried creating patch by using

```
diff -ru old/ new/ > file.patch
```

I got following output in file.patch:

```
Only in old/: abc
Only in new/: cde
```

and when I tried to patch the file I got following error:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

When I try to create patch by using:

```
diff -ruN old/ new/ > file.patch
```

I get empty file.patch.

Is there any way to create a patch that when patched to old would delete *abc* and create *cde* in old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [makepatch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/makepatch/script/makepatch) script is useful for this.  I use this for almost all source-patches, along with diffstat. There is also [applypatch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/makepatch/script/applypatch) (completing the task), though I do not use it myself.

The GNU diff new-file "-N" option does (used to not...) work with the  recursion option "-r".  So you could use

```
diff -r -N old new
```

I just verified that it works for diff 3.0 (which by now is rather old).